# How to write a footer for a table with multiple images

Tags: graphics, header-footer

I am trying to add a footer to a centered table with three images. When I add the footer, the last image disappear and the footer which does not fit in one line is not using more than one line. The images are 1024x1024px.

How can I solve this problem?

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ l c r }
        \includegraphics[scale=0.03]{img/original.png} & 
        \includegraphics[scale=0.03]{img/gauss2.png} & 
        \includegraphics[scale=0.03]{img/gauss5.png} \\
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{De izquierda a derecha, imagen original (dendrita de una neurona de hipocampo de un cultivo transfectado con Actina-GFP) y resultados de aplicar el filtro de Gauss con $\sigma = 2,5$} \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Comment: `c` as used in your multicolumn is always one line, use `p{5cm}` or whatever width you need if you want it to line break, or more simply just put that text outside the table after a blank line so it is a new paragraph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ l c r }
        \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-a} &
        \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-b} &
        \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image} \\
        \multicolumn{3}{p{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}}{\footnotesize De izquierda a derecha, imagen original (dendrita de una neurona de hipocampo de un cultivo transfectado con Actina-GFP) y resultados de aplicar el filtro de Gauss con $σ= 2,5$} \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The tabular isn't doing anything useful here, just use

```
    \begin{center}

    \includegraphics[scale=0.03]{img/original.png} 
    \includegraphics[scale=0.03]{img/gauss2.png} 
    \includegraphics[scale=0.03]{img/gauss5.png}


    De izquierda a derecha, imagen original 
   (dendrita de una neurona de hipocampo de un 
   cultivo transfectado con Actina-GFP) y resultados
   de aplicar el filtro de Gauss con $\sigma = 2,5$

   \end{center}
```

Comment: How can I get the text below the images justified?

Comment: @Trollkemada move it out of the center environment?

Comment: But then it doesn't look like a comment to the pictures, it looks like a new paragraph. How can I make it look like a picture footnote being justified?

Comment: @Trollkemada you could use a `\caption` if it is a caption, or in the center environment use \parbox{6cm}{the text...} so you centre a justified narrow block or ...

Answer (score 0):

You need not use tabular environment. Instead straight way you can achieve the desired result as shown below. \hspace could be used to separate picture img

Correct Code:

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\flushleft

\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{albt.png} \hspace{0.5cm}
\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{back.png} \hspace{0.5cm} 
\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{bnklogo.png}

De izquierda a derecha, imagen original (dendrita de una neurona de hipocampo de un cultivo transfectado \%con \%Actina-GFP) y resultados de aplicar el filtro de Gauss con $\sigma = 2,5$

\end{document}